# Multiplying 2D array by the correct index's scaler in another 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

When attempting to multiply the array of

```
v = [ ['x1','y1','z1'], ['x2','y2','z2'] ]
```

by the correct index of the array of scalers

```
 b = [ ['t1','c1'], ['t2','c2'] ]
```

I expect to get the output:

````
```
[
[ [x1 * t1, y1 * t1, z1 * t1], [x2 * c1, y2 * c1, z2 * c1] ],
[ [x1 * t2, y1 * t2, z1 * t2], [x2 * c2, y2 * c2, z2 * c2] ]
]
```
````

I can achieve this by doing the following loop:

```
out = []
for i in b:
   for h in range(len(v):
       out.append(v[h] * i[h])
```

How would I go about multiplying the matrices properly in numpy?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an outer product.

Just for the fun of it, I'll stick with your strings, but create `object` dtype arrays:

```
In [677]: v = np.array([ ['x1','y1','z1'], ['x2','y2','z2'] ],object)           
In [678]: v                                                                     
Out[678]: 
array([['x1', 'y1', 'z1'],
       ['x2', 'y2', 'z2']], dtype=object)
In [679]: b = np.array([ ['t1','c1'], ['t2','c2'] ] ,object)                    
In [680]: v.shape                                                               
Out[680]: (2, 3)
In [681]: b.shape                                                               
Out[681]: (2, 2)
```

Then if I use `broadcasting` and `plus` (which for strings is a `join`) I get:

```
In [683]: v[None,:,:]+b[:,:,None]                                               
Out[683]: 
array([[['x1t1', 'y1t1', 'z1t1'],
        ['x2c1', 'y2c1', 'z2c1']],

       [['x1t2', 'y1t2', 'z1t2'],
        ['x2c2', 'y2c2', 'z2c2']]], dtype=object)
```

This multiplies the (2,3) array with a (2,2) by expanding them to (1,2,3) and (2,2,1) => (2,2,3)

The same thing, but with numeric arrays, allowing me to use either + or *:

```
In [684]: V = np.arange(10,70,10).reshape(2,3)                                  
In [685]: B = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)                                       
In [686]: V[None,:,:]+B[:,:,None]                                               
Out[686]: 
array([[[11, 21, 31],
        [42, 52, 62]],

       [[13, 23, 33],
        [44, 54, 64]]])
In [687]: V[None,:,:]*B[:,:,None]                                               
Out[687]: 
array([[[ 10,  20,  30],
        [ 80, 100, 120]],

       [[ 30,  60,  90],
        [160, 200, 240]]])
```

---

Your loop code isn't quite the same (same combinations, but different shape)

```
In [697]: out = [] 
     ...: for i in b: 
     ...:     for h in range(2): 
     ...:         out.append(v[h] + i[h]) 
     ...: np.array(out)                                                         
Out[697]: 
array([['x1t1', 'y1t1', 'z1t1'],
       ['x2c1', 'y2c1', 'z2c1'],
       ['x1t2', 'y1t2', 'z1t2'],
       ['x2c2', 'y2c2', 'z2c2']], dtype=object)

In [699]: out = [] 
     ...: for i in B: 
     ...:     for h in range(2): 
     ...:         out.append(V[h] * i[h]) 
     ...: np.array(out)                                                         
Out[699]: 
array([[ 10,  20,  30],
       [ 80, 100, 120],
       [ 30,  60,  90],
       [160, 200, 240]])
```

---

`einsum` is another way of expressing these combinations:

```
In [708]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ijk',B,V)                                           
Out[708]: 
array([[[ 10,  20,  30],
        [ 80, 100, 120]],

       [[ 30,  60,  90],
        [160, 200, 240]]])
```

If I tell it to sum the `j` dimension, I get the matrix product, `np.dot(B,V)`:

```
In [709]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',B,V)                                            
Out[709]: 
array([[ 90, 120, 150],
       [190, 260, 330]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the above problem is:

```
out = np.tensordot(b, v, 1)
```

Comment: That's just `np.dot(b,v)`.  A similar combination of elements, but sums the middle dimension, producing a (2,3) array (the OP shows a (2,2,3) array).